# Python code works in Spyder but not in Command Line

Tags: python, matplotlib

when I use this code in Spyder it works, but when I try to launch it from the terminal it produces an error:

```
miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 722, in __init__
raise ValueError('verts must be a list of (N, 3) array-like')
```

Why do I get an error in Terminal but not in Spyder?
Where is the Problem?

```
def patch(x,y,z, axis=None, view=None, facecolor=None, edgecolor=None, alpha=None):
    pltshow = False
    if x.shape != y.shape != z.shape:
        raise ValueError("Arrays müssen die gleiche Größe haben.")
    if axis == None:
        fig = plt.figure()
        axis = fig.add_subplot(axis='3d')
        pltshow = True
        
    if facecolor == None:
        facecolor = (0,0,0,1)
    if edgecolor == None:
        edgecolor = (1,1,1,0.2)
    if view == None:
        view = [45,45]
    axis.view_init(elev = view[1], azim = view[0])
    
    verts = []
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        verts.extend(list(zip(x[:,j],y[:,j],z[:,j])))
    
    axis.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, edgecolors=edgecolor, facecolors = facecolor, alpha = alpha))
    
    if pltshow:
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback, and fix the indentation in your code snippet.

Comment: check the enviroment that are you using in spyder then use it on the terminal

Comment: Matplotlib 3.5.1 added a test to make sure that `verts` in `Poly3DCollection(verts, ...)` is a *list* of vertices.  Previously, a single polygon was also accepted.  If this is your case, you can change the code to wrap the vertices in a list:  `Poly3DCollection([verts], ...)`.